# DJANGO how to REMOVE url parameters?

Tags: python, django, url, url-pattern

What would be the best way to remove parameters from url in django? For instance when facebook adds `fbclid`? I am trying to do a redirect directly in `urlpatterns` but the parameters keep getting passed through.

For some reason I assumed this would be some simple command like `allow_parameters=False` or something.

For example go from

```
"https://www.example.com/?fbclid=IwAR2MOZRZga4dwgOXK4GDznLEuynTLw.."
```

to

```
"https://www.example.com/"
```

Comment: Actually using a [redirect][1] in your code is a simple way to get rid of the GET URL parameters.

Further References:
 * https://realpython.com/django-redirects/


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: I was hoping to fix it directly in urls because I don't want to redirect every call to the homepage. And also, I want to be able to do it for the login page, etc. Is there a was to check if parameters were added in urls? I would need something that if there is parameter goes to redirect else goes straight to homepage. I tried using re_path but no luck.

Comment: Okay, let's see. There are probably many ways, one would be using .httaccess if you are using the Apache web server.
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "fbclid=" [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: Also, how does this unwanted id enter your page? Can it be removed from the source code or DB (if the content is loaded) by a search and replace operation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it. 
Facebook adds the parameter automatically to all outgoing links. I though it would be a good idea to find a way to just disallow all parameters (or any string for that matter) attached to routes. 

Shouldn't there be a way in re_path to check if there is anything after base url and the send that to redirect view? I'm trying but I think the problem is that django ignores query strings in url

Answer (score 0):

For now I got this to strip all parameters before login. And then similar logic can be added to individual views

```
def login_check(request):
    if len(request.GET) < 1:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return redirect(login_check)
```

and then just add path in urls with `name=login_check` and change default `login_url` in settings to that path (login_check in this case).